# Read variable from file with awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm new using awk and I found it very useful for extracting data from columns. For example in my file I had

```
Data:     1234      23434     31324
```

If I wanted the second column I used:

```
awk '/Data:/ {print $3}' file.txt
```

But next, I had some variables inside the file, let's say:

```
variable_1=1
variable_2=4
```

How can I extract only the value? how can I extract the name of the variable by knowing the value?

Comment: @anubhava Do not works

Comment: See answer below from @hek2mgl , that should work for you

Comment: You can use `variable_1` the same way you're using `Data`, to select the single line you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` offers to specify the field delimiter:

```
awk -F'=' '$1 == "variable_1" {print $2}' file
```

Prints:

```
1
```

Comment: Yes, it specifies a new delimiter, but how can I only the value. It worked, but in the case of having more characters to the right it will also extract them.

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar Can you give a specific example of input data and your expected output?

Comment: What if my code is commented, e.g.   
'variable_1=1        #This variable is for the number one'. With your solution I get as output>>1        #This variable is for the number one

Comment: Instead of talking about edge cases, what do you basically want to do? I mean what is your use case? I'm asking because if you want to parse shell syntax, then you'll probably use the shell for that, not awk.

Comment: I want to extract a variable from a code, how can I use the shell for that? I only try to learn how to use awk...

Comment: When you want to extract a variable from  a shell  script use the shell. period :) `source file.sh; echo "${variable_1}"` I won't advertise bad practice here.

Comment: I mean, sure you could just extract anything after the `=` until the end of the line or a `#`.  But what do you do with this: `var1="hey this is not a # comment"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of things with your file, what do you really want?
Get values:

```
source file.txt
echo "variable_1=${variable_1}"
echo "variable_2=${variable_2}"
```

Get keys corresponding to value 2

```
sed '/=2$/ s/=.*//' file.txt
```